# How to remove union all in last line of output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a query which is fetching all the project/schema with same table name with UNION ALL. But i am getting the output with UNION ALL in all PROJECT / Schema. i am expecting result which should remove the union all from the last project / schema.

Current Output :

```
select 'ProjectA' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectA.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectB' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectB.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectC' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectC.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectD' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectD.event UNION ALL
```

Expected Output :

```
select 'ProjectA' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectA.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectB' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectB.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectC' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectC.event UNION ALL
select 'ProjectD' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ProjectD.event ;
```

Query :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
 Declare
v_sql varchar2(500);
v_sql2 varchar2(500);
v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='ProjectA,ProjectB,ProjectC,ProjectD';

BEGIN


 Dbms_Output.Put_Line('v_prj_id='||v_prj_id);
 --
FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
   ) LOOP

   v_sql :=  'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || 
    '.Table UNION ALL';

   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql);

    --
   END LOOP;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql ;

    v_sql2 :=  RTRIM (v_sql, 'UNION ALL');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 ;
   Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

   END;
   /
```

Comment: But you already do have that solution ? `v_sql2 :=  RTRIM (v_sql, 'UNION ALL');` This removes it. DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=567bbe3d841d40e05885f05be9c67f22

Comment: Why do you have several project tables, all looking the same?

Comment: Yep, that looks like a bad data model. You should fix it, have one project table only and query with `select * from projects where project_name in ('ProjectA', 'ProjectB', 'ProjectC', 'ProjectD')`. So simple :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you had is already doing the trim of your string in `v_sql`
But if you want to execute it all at the same time then you will have to do this:

```
begin
Declare
   v_sql varchar2(500);
   v_sql2 varchar2(500);
   v_prj_id varchar2(4000):='ProjectA,ProjectB,ProjectC,ProjectD';
BEGIN

   FOR i IN (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_prj_id, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
             FROM dual 
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_prj_id, ',') + 1 
   ) LOOP


       v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || '.Table UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ;

   END LOOP;

    v_sql2 :=  RTRIM(v_sql, 'UNION ALL ' || chr(10) ) || ';';

    Dbms_Output.Put_Line (v_sql2);

   END;
end;
/
```

The `v_sql2` will now have the entire desired code.
Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=99f816601aa96cf871c59ad083d3bd1d)

Comment: Thanks for the query. I also need to parse where condition as bind variable in that query. but i am getting error Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

    v_sql :=  v_sql || 'select '''|| i.l ||''' AS "PRJ_ID", EVENT, email,modified_by,modified from ' || i.l || '.SI_Recipient WHERE EVENT = :1 UNION ALL ' || chr(10)   ;
      
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  STRING USING v_event;

Comment: I have seen the question, I will check it when I will have some time. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`RTRIM` is not the correct function. It removes all characters from right present in the whitelist ***so it will trim more than just `UNION ALL`***.

You could use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```sql
SELECT str
     , RTRIM(str, ' UNION ALL') AS bad
     , SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str, ' UNION ALL', -1) - 1) AS good
FROM (
    SELECT 'SELECT * FROM FOO.LLANOINU UNION ALL' AS str FROM dual
) x
```

Comment: That `RTRIM` removes all characters in the set is correct, but no problem in this case, as the string ends on 'event UNION ALL', so ' UNION ALL' including the leading space will get removed. It is good though, you are pointing this out, as the OP may not have been aware of what they are actually doing.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner have a look at the example I made up. Everything until the period is trimmed. `t` does not contain any character from `unioal ` so OP got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You'd usually use string manipulation functions, e.g.

```
v_sql := substr(v_sql, 1, length(v_sql) - length('UNION ALL'));
```